# recode in dplyr giving Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe "employee" like this:

```
Emp_Id,Name,Dept_Id
20203,Sam,1
20301,Rodd,2
30321,Mike,3
40403,Derik,4
```

Now i want to transform this dataframe in a way that the Dept_Id have department names instead of Dept_Id.

I am trying to use `recode` from `dplyr`for this, since my transformation logic comes from a csv, I would have to use a variable in place of transformation logic.

I used read.csv to get my dataframe `df` where my logic (`1=HR,2=IT` and so on) sits and then get it in a list:

```
df:

Source,Target,Transformation
Employee,Emp,"1=HR,2=Sales,3=Finance,4=IT"
```

To get the transaformation login from `df`

```
myList <- as.character(df[1,3])
```

Now replacing the data in employee as per the logic

```
employee$Dept_Id <- recode(employee$Dept_Id,myList)
```

On this line it is giving me:

```
Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed
```

Comment: @Ronak Editted the question for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe `df` has a different structure which makes it difficult to apply functions directly. We need to clean it and bring it in a better format so that it is easy to query on it.

One way to do that is to split the data on `,` and `=` to create a new dataframe (`lookup`) with department ID and Name.

```
lookup <- data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df[1,3]), ",")[[1]],
                        function(x) strsplit(x, "=")[[1]])), row.names = NULL)

lookup
#  X1      X2
#1  1      HR
#2  2   Sales
#3  3 Finance
#4  4      IT
```

Once we have `lookup` then it is easy to `match` by ID and get corresponding name.

```
employee$Dept_Name <- lookup$X2[match(employee$Dept_Id, lookup$X1)]

employee
#  Emp_Id  Name Dept_Id Dept_Name
#1  20203   Sam       1        HR
#2  20301  Rodd       2     Sales
#3  30321  Mike       3   Finance
#4  40403 Derik       4        IT
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Ronak Shah

Comment: If somehow Dept_Id comes from a variable like:
col <- input_data[1,2]
lookup$X2[match(employee$col, lookup$X1)]

Error:Error in -lookup$X2[match(employee$col, lookup$X1)] : 
Error:  invalid argument to unary operator   , what to do?

Comment: @Deep It depends on how `input_data[1,2]` looks like.  The final goal is to create a dataframe which is like `lookup` where one column has `Dept_Id` and the other has `Dept_Name`.

Comment: Nevermind..it was an issue with space while assiging the value with <-, working now.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do this. One way is:

**Method 1:**

```
df$Dept_Id <-  name[match(df$Dept_Id, names(name))]

    Emp_Id Name Dept_Id
1:  20203  Sam      HR
2:  20301 Rodd      IT
```

**Method 2:**

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(Dept_Id_2 = case_when(
        Dept_Id == 1 ~ 'HR',
        Dept_Id == 2 ~ 'IT'
    ))
```

**Method 3:**

```
codes <- list("1" = "HR", "2" = "IT")

df %>% 
    mutate(d2 = recode(Dept_Id, !!!codes))
```

**Setup**

```
df <- fread("
Emp_Id  Name Dept_Id
20203   Sam  1
20301   Rodd 2            
")

name <- c("1" = "HR", "2"="IT")
```

Comment: Thanks @YOHO will give these a try and update you.Cheers and happy new year!

Comment: I tried your answer, however having issues in getting the name as per your setup as the condition you have used in the name <- c(....) are coming from another CSV cell in my case and it is dropping the quotes when reading the data from csv

Comment: You can use the `lookup` table from ronak's answer above, and convert the table to `name` vector using: `name <- lookup$X2; names(name) <-  lookup$X1`

Comment: you can create `codes` using: `codes = setNames(as.list(lookup$X2), lookup$X1)`

Comment: Great answers , @YOLO. Could you explain what the triple exclamation mark `!!!` does `???` :) Didnt find any obvious answers googling

Answer (score 1):

Another way If you don't want to change your existing database and the department list is not too big.

**Assumption:** there is not any missing data in your "employee" database. if any missing data available then need to add one more level of condition.

ifelse is the simple way to apply your logic, I have mentioned that in below code

```
New_DF = ifelse(employee$Dept_Id == 1,"HR",ifelse(employee$Dept_Id == 2,"Sales",ifelse(employee$Dept_Id == 3,"Finance","IT")))
New_DF = cbind(employee,New_DF)
```